# Ubuntu full install on 64gb usb3.0 sandisk

Tags: 14.04, usb, system-installation

So I'm aware that it isn't recommended to run a full Ubuntu install on USB sticks due to the limited read/write cycles as compared to traditional SSDs or hard disks, and the USB connection limits write speeds etc..

I just wanted to know if this applies to newer drives like the one listed above,
The read speed is 130mb/s so it's faster than traditional hard drives.

But I'm unsure about the longevity I can get from this newer USB flash

Is it OK to run a full Ubuntu install from it?

I currently have two windows OS installs on my dedicated hard drive, this is why I rather run Ubuntu straight off my USB.. It's quickly becoming my default OS .

I use ms office web apps when I need to edit docx, deezer.com for music, and overall Ubuntu proves to be pretty awesome.

I game on windows 8.1 and run my piano software on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't make sense to use an expensive 64GB USB 3.0 flash drive for a full installation of Ubuntu due to the limited read/write cycles as you mentioned. All you need for it is an inexpensive 16GB USB flash drive. [How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key? (without using Startup Disk Creator)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator).

Comment: For once I disagree with you...  Read my answer...  :P  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I cannot vouch for this particular USB stick as the technical specifications do not give any information whether this is an [SLC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-level_cell#Single-level_cell) or [MLC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-level_cell) stick.

*However* If you go into any electronics store and *order* and SLC USB stick (they're normally not on stock) ***go for it as an SLC stick is basically a small SSD hard drive on a stick!***

See also [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) and choose user type 1 and read that answer for more background information.

Answer (score -1):

OK, lets do the math;

Size 64 GB

Write speed 50 MB/s

No of writes 10000 to 100000.

64GB x 10000 / 0.05 GB/s = 12800000s or 417 eight hour days

64GB x 100000 / 0.05 GB/s = 128000000s or 4167 eight hour days

Of course it is only written to a small percentage of the time and reading is not detrimental to the drive, so the above figures are an absolute minimum.

My last 64GB USB3 flash drive cost me about $25, the cost works out to about 6 cents a day max.